# How to download images on Colab / AWS ML instance for ML purposes when Images already belong to AWS links

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, google-colaboratory

So I have my images links like:
`https://my_website_name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/XYZ/image_id/crop_image.png`

and I have almost 10M images which I want to use for Deep Learning purpose. I have a script to download the images and save them in desired directories already using `requests` and `PIL`

Most naïve idea that I have and which I have been using my whole life is to first download all the images in my local machine, make a zip and upload it to `Google Drive` where I can just use `gdown` to download it anywhere based on my Network Speed. Or just copy to `Colab` using terminal.

But that data was not so big. Always under 200K images. But now, the data is huge so downloading and again uploading the images will take a whole lot of time in days and on top of that, it'll just make the `Google Drive` run out of space with 10M images. So I am thinking about using `AWS ML` (SageMaker) or something else from `AWS`. So is there a better approach to this? How can I import the data directly to my `SSD` supported based virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS python library `boto3` to connect to the S3 bucket from Colab: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html

Comment: But it'll be as fast as the SSD right? Because I want the data on high speed drives to in and out fast computations.

Comment: If you access the files individually from S3 it won't be as fast as an SSD, since it will be requesting the files over the network from AWS. If you have enough persistent  storage, you could download all the files to it first, however I'm not sure how large your collection of images is. I believe other Google Compute services besides Colab may provide a larger local persistent disk.

Comment: There are around 10M images. So persistence would work only  because I can't download over and over again.